# SKSpriteNode touches began/ended not working as expected when trying to make a button using swift

Tags: button, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

ive subclasses SKSpriteNode and am trying to implement a simple button by overriding the touchesBegan and touchesEnded method of SKSpriteNode and added a couple of methods to animate the button when its pressed/released.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class SimpleButton: SKSpriteNode {

    //called when the user taps the button
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        println("touches began")
        animateForTouchDown()

    }

    //called when the user finishes touching the button
    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        println("touches ended")
        animateForTouchUp()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        println("touches moved")
    }


    func animateForTouchDown() {

        self.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(0.8, duration: 0.1))
        println("animateing for touch down")
    }

    func animateForTouchUp() {

        self.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(1.25, duration: 0.1))
        println("animating for touch up")
    }
}
```

and add the button to my scene like so:

```
    let imageTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "a_button")
    let sprite: SimpleButton = SimpleButton(texture: imageTexture)
    sprite.userInteractionEnabled = true
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 200, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    sprite.color = UIColor.blackColor()
    sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    self.addChild(sprite)
```

this works but only when the the x position of  button is on the right side of the screen. If I move the button to the left side of the screen (x < 200 or so) the only way to get the button to animate is by clicking and dragging then releasing. (it looks like touches began and ended both get called on release of the button when this happens, which is strange)

I have no idea why this is happening. It makes no sense at all to me. Ive added multiple buttons to my scene using the same exact code and the ones on the right side of the screen work great, anything on the left side of the screen past x = 200 or so you have to click and drag to make them work. any ideas? Ive tried multiple simulators, multiple iOS versions, tested on my device running 7.1, they all have the same behavior.

update: It looks like this is happening because im loading my scene in a view controller thats pushed onto a navigation controller stack with the default show(push) animation. Any ideas how I can make this work with the animation? If I select another animation like show detail or modal in my segue it works. But I want the push animation, not the modal.

Comment: The button works at any x position in the scene when I implemented it. Did you update to the latest version of Xcode?

Comment: yes I have the latest version. I think it might just be iOS 8. did it work for you using 8?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code into a new iOS 8.0 sprite kit project and the button reacted (resized and NSLog) to my tap at various x positions.

Comment: ok. It looks like its happening because Im loading my scene in a view controller thats pushed onto a navigation controller using a segue and an animation. It may be the animation thats causing the issue. (im just using the default push animation) I just tried it in a test project using a view controller with no navigation controller and animation and it worked fine. With the navigation controller and animation is when it does not work. Wonder how I can fix that.